# Secure wp-login.php in wordpress using ModSecurity with Nginx on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, login, nginx, wordpress

I am trying to restrict access to WordPress login page to specific IPs with libModSecurity3. I have my WordPress running on ubuntu 20.4, Nginx version 1.19.7. I have installed and setup LibModSecurity with the Nginx web server, compiled it, and it works. I have created a custom rules configuration file and included the following:

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI "@eq /wp-login.php" \
  "chain, \
  id:'2000', \
  phase:1, \
  log, \
  pass"
  SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@ipMatch 122.128.51.1,122.128.51.21" \
    ctl:ruleEngine=DetectionOnly
SecRule REQUEST_URI "@contains wp-login" "id:2001,phase:1,t:lowercase,log,deny,msg:'Warning, Access to WordPress Login page is Restricted'"
```

When I apply the rule and try to access my login page from the IP that I have whitelisted and again included in the above file, I get 403 although I should be able to access the login page. How can I correct this?

Comment: This isn't a solution to your question, but may be a solution to your problem. There are plugins (like All In One WP Security & Firewall) that will let you whitelist your IP address(es) and block all other login attempts. There are a ton of login security plugins available and one of them will more than likely tick all the boxes.

Comment: Thank you. I don't want to use plugins because I don't know how will the ModSecurity interact with it. If I can handle this through the mod security, it would be great.

Comment: If you don't get an answer, then you can check the StackExchange's [WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) section.

Comment: Thank you for telling me about that! I have posted it there.